# Conditional Image - PHP PDO

Tags: php, pdo, conditional-statements

I'm learning PHP PDO - How do you conditionally show an image based on whether it exists? I have the code below at the moment but if no image exists for an article then there's a place holder for broken image link..

Code:

```
 $ARTICLE = $conn->prepare("SELECT blog_title, blog_article, blog_img FROM Blog WHERE blog_title=:blog_title");
 $ARTICLE->bindParam(':blog_title', $blog_title, PDO::PARAM_STR, 25);
 $ARTICLE->execute();

<?php
 while ($r = $ARTICLE->fetch()) {
 ?>

 <h1>
    <?PHP
echo ($r['blog_title']);
   ?>
 </h1>
  <img src="images/<?PHP echo ($r['blog_img']);?>">
   <?PHP
   echo ($r['blog_article']);
   ?>

 <?php
  }
  ?>

  <h1><?PHP
 echo ($r['blog_title']);?></h1>
  <img src="images/<?PHP echo ($r['blog_img']);?>">
  <?PHP echo ($r['blog_article']);
 ?>

  <?php
 }
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way:

```
if (!empty($r['blog_img']) && file_exists('path-to-image/' . $r['blog_img'])) {
    // show blog_img
} else {
    // show default image
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to check if the field from the database is not empty, then if the image exists.
Then you can display the image or the default one.

```
if(!empty($r['blog_img']) && file_exists('images/'.$r['blog_img'])) { 
    echo '<img src="images/'.$r['blog_img'].'">';
} else {
    echo '<img src="images/brokenlink.gif">';
}
```

Comment: Add some additional information along with your answer please.

Comment: You should also check if $r['blog_img'] is not empty. Otherwise you are checking if folder exists on server and it will return true.

Comment: Thanks for the notes, I'll revise.